# Best practice when object is undefined if - else

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if my code approaching is good, I would like to:

1. Check if an object exist
2. If not exist create it and assign it properties
3. If already exist just assign properties

what I have now is the follow code, But I don't like to write two times the same line

```
function doSomething(_whatever){
    if(typeof someobject === "undefined"){
        someobject = { //dont exist
            profile : "some value",
            status : []
        }

        someobject.status.push(_whatever);
    }else{
        someobject.status.push(_whatever); //because already exist
    }
}
```

what is a better way to write this snippet? or do it in a better and less repetitive?

thanks in advance

------ original function

```
function addPerson(_person){
    var people = Iee.dashboard.analytics.data.people.data;      
    if(typeof people[_person.Id_Emp] === "undefined"){
        people[_person.Id_Emp] = {
            profile : _person,
            status : []
        }

        people[_person.Id_Emp].status.push({Id_Emp : _person.Id_Emp, status : _person.Estatus1, estatusby : _person.Centro_de_trabajo});
    }else{
        people[_person.Id_Emp].status.push({Id_Emp : _person.Id_Emp, status : _person.Estatus1, estatusby : _person.Centro_de_trabajo});
    }

    addBlackList(_person);
}
```

Comment: (not to fix your problem, but just a suggestion) - Remove your `else` and put `someobject.status.push(_whatever);` right after the `if`. It needs to be executed no matter what, so why duplicate that line?

Comment: You don't know if the object exist already. So if the code execute that line and the object doesn't exist will crash the browser cause the object is undefined...

Comment: Note that your first and second snippets are quite different. In the first you're checking existence of an _object_, in the second - if an object (`people`) has a certain _property_. Javascript has a [dedicated operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @thg435 totally right ... man... thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do this is a redundant check:

```
someobject = someobject || {
    project:"some value",
    status:[]
};
```

Comment: and after this you can assign the values?

Comment: Absolutely. This basically creates the object with default values if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 4):

Simplified code

```
function addPerson(_person){
        var people = Iee.dashboard.analytics.data.people.data;      
        people[_person.Id_Emp] = people[_person.Id_Emp] || {
                profile : _person,
                status : []
            };

            people[_person.Id_Emp].status.push({Id_Emp : _person.Id_Emp, status : _person.Estatus1, estatusby : _person.Centro_de_trabajo});

        addBlackList(_person);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man I market @Kolink as right just because he answered first. but both are totally right...

Answer (score 1):

In this case you *expect it to be either an object or undefined*, but not a string, a number, etc., so you can just check if it has a truthy value.

```
function addPerson(_person) {
    var people = Iee.dashboard.analytics.data.people.data,
        person = people[_person.Id_Emp];

    if (!person) person = {
        profile: _person,
        status: []
    };
    person.status.push({
        Id_Emp: _person.Id_Emp, 
        status: _person.Estatus1, 
        estatusby: _person.Centro_de_trabajo
    });

    addBlackList(_person);
}
```

This should perform slightly better than the redundant check mentioned in other answers, as it will only assign a value to the variable if a (truthy) value is not already present.

Just for fun, here's an ultra-condensed version:

```
function addPerson(_person) {
    var people = Iee.dashboard.analytics.data.people.data, id = _person.Id_Emp;

    (people[id] || { profile: _person, status: [] }).status.push({
        Id_Emp: id, status: _person.Estatus1, estatusby: _person.Centro_de_trabajo
    });
    addBlackList(_person);
}
```

Comment: cool!!! this sounds better... But what happend if people[_person.Id_Emp] is undefined at first is not going to crash the browser? I mean will try to access, obviously with not success.

Comment: As long as `a` and `b` are defined and can have properties, `a[b.c]` should not cause an error, even if `b.c` is not defined. So, it's safe if `people` `_person` are objects. Try running this in the console: `var a = {}, b = {}; alert(a[b.c]);`